# How to get username and password of mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am trying to connect to mysql database from java and I forgot username and password of Mysql plz help me to get username and pass.

Comment: Do you have super-user (or `mysql` user) privileges on the database machine?

Comment: yes i have that privilege..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't  get back your password but you can reset it:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html